# Double subscript error - still compiling as expected

Tags: equations, pdftex, subscripts

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{second}
\Sigma _A _\subseteq _\Theta m (A) = 1
\end{equation}
```

and I'm getting the following errors:

```
! Double subscript. \Sigma _A _
! Double subscript. \Sigma _A _\substeq_
```

When I compile the PDF the equation looks as expected:

[image: compiled equation]

How can I remove these errors?

Comment: If you run LaTeX in interactive mode and type `h` at the prompt, you'll get the message `I treat \`x_1_2' essentially like \`x_1{}_2'.` Which is why the result looks reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the official LaTeX manual, subscripts and superscripts are always braced, for instance,

```
x^{2} x_{i}
```

It turns out that when the subscript or superscript consists of a single object, braces can often (but not always) be omitted, so also

```
x^2 x_i
```

are valid. But try with `X_\notin` and you'll be surprised.

I'm guilty of not using braces in those cases. However, when the subscript or superscript consists of several objects, it ***must*** be braced:

```
\sum_{A\subseteq\Theta} m(A) = 1
```

is the correct syntax. (I guess you want the summation symbol `\sum` rather than `\Sigma`.)

Comment: The brackets fixed my problem, many thanks. (Sigma is the required symbol in this case)